Getting a summary of a dataframe that will have a column of dataframes containing the data of each group in R
I would normally use the following code to get what I want, but was wondering what would be a good way to do it now that cur_data is being deprecated.
df <- data.frame(col_a = c("a","a","b","c","c"),
  col_b=c(1,2,3,4,5),
  col_c=c("q","w","e","r","t"))
dfdata <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(col_a) %>% dplyr::summarise(data = list(dplyr::cur_data()))
dfdata
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  col_a data
  <chr> <list>
1 a     <tibble [2 × 2]>
2 b     <tibble [1 × 2]>
3 c     <tibble [2 × 2]>
dfdata$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  col_b col_c
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 q
2     2 w

Thank you!
I have been looking through the documentation of pick() and reframe() but wasn't able to figure anything out.

I would use tidyr::nest():
library(tidyr)

dfdata <- df %>% 
  nest(.by = col_a, .key = "data")

But an approach similar to yours using pick() would be:
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(col_a) %>% 
  summarise(data = list(pick(everything())))

Result from either approach:
#> dfdata
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  col_a data
  <chr> <list>
1 a     <tibble [2 × 2]>
2 b     <tibble [1 × 2]>
3 c     <tibble [2 × 2]>

#> dfdata$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  col_b col_c
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 q
2     2 w


For completeness simply using across with tidyselect
df %>% 
  summarise(data = list(across(everything())), .by = col_a)
  col_a       data
1     a 1, 2, q, w
2     b       3, e
3     c 4, 5, r, t

(df %>% 
  summarise(data = list(across(everything())), .by = col_a))$data[1]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  col_b col_c
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 q    
2     2 w


This is what purrr::nest_by does:
library(purrr)
df_data = df |> nest_by(col_a)
df_data
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
# # Rowwise:  col_a
#   col_a               data
#   <chr> <list<tibble[,2]>>
# 1 a                [2 × 2]
# 2 b                [1 × 2]
# 3 c                [2 × 2]

df_data$data[[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   col_b col_c
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 q    
# 2     2 w    


There's another:
dfdata <- dplyr::group_nest(df, col_a)

> dfdata
# A tibble: 3 × 2
col_a               data
<chr> <list<tibble[,2]>>
1 a                [2 × 2]
2 b                [1 × 2]
3 c                [2 × 2]

> dfdata$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
col_b col_c
<dbl> <chr>
1     1 q    
2     2 w 

